# Core-Data NSPredicate with multiple to-many conditions

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Helo guys,

I have the following core-data database:

(Unfortunately I cannot embed the image, because of the spam prevention!)

Data base model image: http://snapplr.com/eqx9

I am trying to create a fetchRequest, which fetches all FC objects whose `fcCollection.fcSets.trainingSet` property is an object in my code BUT are not in `trainingSet.memorizationSession.mistakeFCs`. I want to use it in `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I have tried so many different things and they all didnt work (Unfortunately I didnt save what I tried, so I cannot post).
But I have tried SUBQUERIES and so on. My last approach is the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: kFCMistakeEntityName
                                                      inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];
            [fetchRequest setEntity: entity];

            NSPredicate *subPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
                         @"memorizationSession.trainingSet == %@", _trainingSet];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate: subPredicate];

            NSArray *mistakeFCs = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error: nil];

            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
                         @"ANY fcCollection.fcSets.trainingSet == %@ && NOT mistakeFC in %@", _trainingSet, mistakeFCs];
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> 2011-05-18 22:26:55.643 testApp[9464:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (mistakeFC IN {FCMistake: empty FC; correctFC: 0, FCMistake: 55; correctFC: 9, FCMistake: empty FC; correctFC: 3, FCMistake: empty FC; correctFC: 9, FCMistake: empty FC; correctFC: 4})'

This must be possible somehow! Thanks in advance for helping!

Greetings, Kim

Answer (score 1):

From the Predicate Programming Guide:

> The Core Data SQL store supports only
>   one to-many operation per query;
>   therefore in any predicate sent to the
>   SQL store, there may be only one
>   operator (and one instance of that
>   operator) from ALL, ANY, and IN.

so if you are using the SQL datastore you can only represent one one-to-many relationship in your predicates. If you change to some other persistence store it seems to imply that this particular restriction is lifted.